# How to drain pgbouncer connections

Tags: pgbouncer

I have 2 pgbouncers, pgbouncers-1 & pgbouncer-2 both are running on RHEL, I need to apply OS patch which requires OS reboot. how can I reboot pgbouncer server without disruption on connections. I am thinking rolling reboot, 1 pgbouncer at a time, is that helps?
Is there any way to drain pgbouncer connections?

I am thinking try rolling reboot